# Database structure to send messages between registered customers/guests and company agents

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, entity-relationship

**TL;DR**

Facebook-like messaging system with Laravel/MySQL, where also guests are able to send messages to the company agents. The company agents can start conversations with registered customers.

**Full details**

I'm trying to create a system that allows a registered customer/guest to send messages to the company agents and vice versa but I'm stuck in the relationships between the sender/receiver of the message and the message itself.

This is a list of requirements for this system (I already covered almost all items):

- Allow both registered customers and guests to send messages. Customers and guests can only send messages to the company departments. This means that customers can't send messages to other customers.
- When creating the message, the creator needs to tell what type of message is creating by selecting an option from a list of categories.
- Each category needs to be received by a "role" (So, billing related messages will be received by the financial department, support messages will be received by customer service, etc).
- The messages can come from 1) a contact form available in the Contact page of the website where are asked fist name, last name, email, phone number, subject and message; and 2) emails sent by users (then the system will receive the emails via webhook and store them properly).
- All departments can contact any user (registered or not) at any time. This means that they can reply to messages but also can "start" the conversation (example: A message asking to confirm/update details).

Here is what I currently have:

[image]

This covers almost everything, except for the users/guest messages relationships.

Each message is created by someone (registered customer, registered company agent or a guest) and is directed to someone (registered customer to a department, guest to a department, registered company agent to a registered customer or registered company agent replying to a guest).

My current approach is to use two tables: `Guest` and `User`. The `User` table will contain both customers and agents (this one is easy, I just need to assign the proper role). This means that I need to store in the `Message` table  a sender_type (guest or user), sender_id (the id), receiver_type (guest or user) and receiver_id. But, for example, when Customer1 needs to send a message to the Billing Department, I don't know which agent will reply to that message. Does this mean that I should store "null" in the receiver fields? This may lead to many rows with null columns.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Having two separate tables is one approach. You would want to ensure that a given guest user can still access their conversation after the message is sent so you would want to generate the guest user ID and ideally have some other authentication to access these messages (securely).

In terms of actual user, I would just have a table with user profile data stored in it with 'user type' as your registered customer (C) or registered company agent (A) types.

Although you could simply put this in one 'user' table by generating the guest profile ID and authentication outside of MySQL within PHP and then insert this into your user table. This would simplify things a great deal more in terms of querying the data and indexing.

Either will work, but I would go with the second option personally.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply @LovelyBanter! Will this second option lead to a bigger 'user' table? Currently, my user table is very simple: id, name, email, password, status, created_at, updated_at.

Comment: No worries @TJistooshort! It will add more rows to the 'user' table yes, but its more efficient to store them in one table rather than two. At the very least I would add 'user_type' to that column list.